# Encoding from Western European (ISO) (code page 28591, iso-8859-1) to Thai (Windows) (code page 874, windows-874) Using PHP

Tags: php

I have some encoded string. I need to convert in Thai.

Please find below string

'ªÙªÑÂ  à¾ç§Íé¹'

I tried this website http://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx
select encode with `iso-8859-1` decode with `windows-874`

Then it will return Thai string.

Now, How i can do it with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is done with this function

```
function utf8_to_tis620($string) {
       $str = $string;
       $res = "";
       for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
          if (ord($str[$i]) == 224) {
            $unicode = ord($str[$i+2]) & 0x3F;
            $unicode |= (ord($str[$i+1]) & 0x3F) << 6;
            $unicode |= (ord($str[$i]) & 0x0F) << 12;
            $res .= chr($unicode-0x0E00+0xA0);
            $i += 2;
          } else {
            $res .= $str[$i];
          }
       }
       return $res;
    }
```

If you call and pass this **ªÙªÑÂ à¾ç§Íé¹** string it will convert and return Thai value.